# Erro ao instalar HAXM no Mac OS X

Tags: android-studio, osx, mac

Bom dia. 
Sou novo no Mac e estou tendo dificuldades para instalar o `Android Studio` no Sistema Operacional.
O seguinte erro é exibido para mim na instalação do `HAXM`:

[image: c<code>insira o código aqui</code>]

Li em alguns lugares que devo habilitar o Intel Corporation Apps nas `Preferências do Sistema > Segurança e Privacidade`, porém não aparece esta opção para mim :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A versão do `MacOs` que estou usando é a `10.14.3`

O que devo fazer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui instalar o HAXM manualmente, baixando do seguinte link:

https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/tag/v7.5.1